# Brakes groaning noise while coming to stop or releasing the break

Tags: noise, braking, rav4

2013 rav4 makes some strange (groan) noise, as car comes to stop or as I release the brake slightly.

Sounds (and stops) come very rough if car is on downhill and are not smooth.

Definitely something caused by metal friction but nothing like worn pads scratching/squeaking (pads are new, but not sure about quality).

Here are the audios:

Downhill: https://youtu.be/Yp7EvwZGIcc

Ground level: [https://youtu.be/qONXhN4SuKM](http://youtu.be/qONXhN4SuKM)

Any ideas whats the cause?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like one of the pads might be cocked or getting stuck a little bit. in the hardware. I would say Take everything apart and clean and re check it all and re-lube it all including the slide pins.